# Cassandra :[Invalid query] message="PRIMARY KEY column "lng" cannot be restricted

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am getting an error while executing following query in cqlsh

**Query**

```
SELECT * FROM ragchews.disc_location WHERE country_code = 12 AND lat > 100.00 and lat < 120.00 and lng > 50 and lng < 100 allow filtering;
```

**Table**

```
CREATE TABLE ragchews.disc_location (
    country_code int,
    lat float,
    lng float,
    uid text,
    PRIMARY KEY (country_code, lat, lng, uid)
);
```

**Error:**

```
code=2200 [Invalid query] message="PRIMARY KEY column "lng" cannot be restricted (preceding column "ColumnDefinition{name=lat, type=org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.FloatType, kind=CLUSTERING_COLUMN, componentIndex=0, indexName=null, indexType=null}" is either not restricted or by a non-EQ relation)"
```

**Cassandra version**

```
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.2 | CQL spec 3.2.0 | Native protocol v3]
```

---

Edit 1

Following query works fine for me

```
SELECT * FROM ragchews.disc_location WHERE country_code=91 and lat > 32 and lat < 100  allow filtering;
```

That looks like something is wrong with column `lng`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have such query. You can add `> or <` for your last part of your where clause clustering key, provided `=` for the preceding keys. For example the following query will work fine,

```
SELECT * FROM ragchews.disc_location WHERE country_code = 12 AND lat = 100.00 and lng > 50 and lng < 100;
```

or even the following will work,

```
SELECT * FROM ragchews.disc_location WHERE country_code = 12 AND lat = 100.00 and lng = 50 and uid > '500' and uid  < '1000'
```

But two where clause having `> or < condition` will wont work.

Comment: Is their any way to achieve same. Any trick/workaround. I don't want to  take big data set in memory and process it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this right, you have to use the '=' operator for all composite key columns except the last one. The last one (in your case **lng**) can be restricted with '<' or '>'.

Here the link: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-in-cql-3-0

Comment: I wonder how i missed such important line in the link you mentioned. Any ways, rereading the link was helpful. +1 for link