# Spark Cassandra Connector IN statement in where clause

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I am using Spark 1.3.1 and Spark Connector. I wrote a query like

```
rdd.select("foo", "bar").where("date > ?", date)
```

this works very well. I want to modify my query as

```
val catList = List(1, 2, 3) 
rdd.select("foo", "bar").where("date > ?", date).where("cat in (?)", catList)
```

but this gives me an error. I want to know what is the right syntax for the "where" method so that it can do a `IN` query.

Edit::

This works for me

```
val catList = List(1, 2, 3)
val query = rdd.select("foo", "bar").where("date > ?", date).filter(r => catList.contains(r.getInt("cat")))
```

but i wonder if we could have put the in check in the where method because I feel that the where method works better than filter as far as performance is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

It should work by removing the parenthesis around ?:

```
rdd.select("foo", "bar").where("date > ?", date).where("cat in ?", catList)
```

Comment: gives an error `PRIMARY KEY column "cat" cannot be restricted (preceding column "date" is restricted by a non-EQ relation)`

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27251237/cassandra-invalid-query-message-primary-key-column-lng-cannot-be-restricte